# Parsing using Jackson

Tags: java, json, parsing, jackson

{ "Person" : { "age" : "2", "Location" : "san jose"} }

Suppose I had the above JSON string, I'm having trouble understanding how to parse out the Location from the JSON. Using an ObjectMapper, is there a way of doing this (in Java)?

Comment: What don't you understand?

Comment: Which method could be used, and how to use it.

Comment: Have you looked at a Jackson tutorial? Stackoverflow is not a tutorial provider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for the record, it is is pretty simple using [the Jackson tree model](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonTreeModel). Here is an example:

```
public class JacksonTree {
    public static final String JSON = "{ \"Person\" : { \"age\" : \"2\", " +
            "\"Location\" : \"san jose\"} }";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        System.out.println(mapper.readTree(JSON)
                .get("Person").get("Location").asText());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
san jose
```

Comment: I am getting the error that: The method path(String) is undefined for the type String. I see on the API that it should be defined, any idea why it is not working?

Comment: Thanks, but I am getting the same error (Except for the get method).

Comment: @user3249763 actually I was wrong about the version. The path(String) exists in 1.X as well as in 2.X.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse that to an object an the get the value. Example

```
import java.io.IOException;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;


public class JacksonParser {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String json = "{ \"Person\" : { \"age\" : \"2\", \"Location\" : \"san jose\"} }";
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try {
            JsonNode actualObj = mapper.readTree(json);
            System.out.println(actualObj.findValue("Location"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```